# Create an article translation(s) via hook_form_alter?

Tags: hooks, 8, forms

I would like to submit an article in English but when I press submit button I would like to create its translation(s) as well. Can I do it with hook_form_alter?

I have this now:

```
 /**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */

function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

  drupal_set_message($form_id);

  switch ($form_id) {

    case 'node_article_form':

      $form['actions']['unpublish']['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_node_article_form_submit';
      $form['actions']['publish']['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_node_article_form_submit';
      break;

  }

}

function mymodule_node_article_form_submit($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  drupal_set_message('Running custom submit handler...');
}
```